# htaccess redirect from subdomain directory to main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, regex

I need redirect all requests from subdomain specific directory to main domain

Example:

```
dev.example.com/directory/test
```

need to redirect to

```
example.com/directory/test
```

(redirect only requests with directory `directory`)

Comment: Does the subdomain and main domain point to the same area of the filesystem? Is `/directory` a physical directory?

Comment: perhaps you should read the documentation. What you describe here is a task, not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the `.htaccess` file at the root of your subdomain you can add the following mod_rewrite directives to redirect to the domain apex:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

> What if i have several subdomains and i wanna redirect it not only from dev.*, but from other subdomains .... Subdomain and main domain point to same directories

To redirect from several specific subdomains then you can modify the above rule to read:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev0\.example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev1\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Note there is no `OR` flag on the last condition.

To redirect *any* subdomain then you can use a more encompassing regex. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: What if i have several subdomains and i wanna redirect it not only from dev.*, but from other subdomains

Comment: Where do these subdomains point to? Does the subdomain and main domain point to the same area of the filesystem? Is /directory a physical directory?

Comment: Subdomain and main domain point to same directories

For example
dev.example.com/directory/test to example.com/directory/test
dev0.example.com/directory/test1 to example.com/directory/test1

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what would I need to do to rewrite the first lot of rules so that it targets a subdirectory subdomain e.g. `https://example.com/directory`?